# LILYGO T-Display-S3 doesn't allow to upload Arduino's sketch

Tags: esp32

I was developing my code at the LILYGO T-Display-S3 on my MacBook Air, when suddenly after I pressed the 'Upload' button, the console showed an error as below:

```
A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP32-C3: No serial data received.
For troubleshooting steps visit: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esptool/en/latest/troubleshooting.html
Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 2
```

And for Windows

```
Serial port COM10
```

There was nothing weird in my code. After this I tried to change cable, upload from my Windows, also changed port number, but the error stays... I'm not able to upload even an empty sketch now. Is something wrong with a connector?
I'm able to get board information in Arduino's software and also see the device on the port.

*I'm able to upload code to my esp32, so I don't think that settings, or connection cable is wrong.

Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image: error]

Comment: COM10 is a serial port name for Windows. Serial ports have very different-looking names on macOS. So there’s something wrong in your settings somehow.

Comment: @jcaron screen above with COM10 and also error msg is from Windows. In Mac I'm getting another name

Comment: in Mac i got: `A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP32-C3: No serial data received.
For troubleshooting steps visit: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esptool/en/latest/troubleshooting.html
Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 2`

Comment: On Windows, check the Windows Device Manager to find the correct port (or to verify there is one: compare the list of devices when your board is connected or isn't). On macOS, check `ls /dev/tty.*` (likewise, with the board connected or not). What's the name of the port you use on macOS?

Comment: @jcaron on windows it is at 10, on Mac it is at tty.usbmodem1101

Comment: @jcaron when I connect the device it first recognize it as another device, so I set the right one in Board menu, but the error stands same, I think USB-C on the board is somehow defective.